# sencha touch + phonegap integration

Tags: cordova, extjs

For long time I'm trying to integrate sencha touch 2.1 and phonegap with no success.
Few days ago I found "Sencha Cordova Builder - Automated Builds for PhoneGap Projects". I did all the instructions to integrate sencha touch with phonegap,  installed JDK, android SDK, ant and adb.
The problem is, when I try to build package, I get the following error:

```
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\wamp\www\testbuilder\build.xml:9: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ant": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

But ant is installed, when I type `ant` on the console I get the following message:

```
build file :build.xml does not exist 
build failed
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you type `ant` in the Windows command line? To me it sounds like ANT's path is not set into Windows environmental PATH.

Check the following guide, especially section 3B at the bottom:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Quote:
`Finally, you may need to include %ANT_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type ant. If the program can not be found add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %ANT_HOME% environment variable.`

EDIT:
The message you actually get is correct, see my comment below for rectification.

Comment: when i type ant in the command line , i get the following :build file :build.xml does not exist 
build failed  my path's :C:\Users\mkhanduqji\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.0.0.250;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\java\ant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin

Comment: Ah, I got your first post wrong. This is the message you should get when you type in `ant` and no build file is provided or can be find. So you ant installation is just fine.

Can you post the contents of the C:\wamp\www\testbuilder\build.xml file? Perhaps there is a wrong path/location in there?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="myApp1" default=".help">
    <import file="${basedir}/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml"/>
 <import file="/sencha-cordova-builder-master/build-cordova.xml" />
 <target name="-after-build" depends="-build-android" />

Comment: <target name="-after-build-android">
    
 <exec executable="ant">
        <arg value="-buildfile" />
        <arg value="${cordova.android.project}/build.xml" />
        <arg value="debug" />
    </exec>

    <exec executable="adb">
        <arg value="install" />
        <arg value="-r" />
        <arg value="${cordova.android.project}/bin/${app.name}-debug.apk" />
    </exec>
 </target>

Comment: this folder sencha-cordova-builder-master in c: and phonegap in c: also